# apply css to php menu

Tags: php, html, css

I want my code to dispaly a css menu like on e commerce sites please help me to apply css on this code

```
    echo "<ul>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) //fetching data from database
    {
         if ($row['Count'] > 0) //THIS IS PARENT MENU
         {
             $url ='show_cat.php?catid='.($row['id']);
             echo "<li class='list'><a  class='list_link'  href='.$url.'>" . $row['label'] . "</a>";
             display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
             echo "</li>";
         } 
         elseif ($row['Count']==0) //THIS IS SUB MENU
         {
                 $url ='show_cat.php?catid='.($row['id']);
                 echo "<li><a class='list_link'      href='.$url.'>" . $row['label'] . "</a></li>";
         } 
         else;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

My web page looks like below but I want to display it into `dropdown menu` with category and when I hover on it it shows the subcategory of that category.

### MP3s & Cloud Player

- MP3 Music Store
- Cloud Player for Web
- Cloud Player for Android
- Cloud Player for iOS

### Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry

- Clothing
- Shoes
- Handbags
- Accessories
- Luggage
- Jewelry
- Watches

### Books

- Books
- Children's Books
- Textbooks
- Audiobooks
- Magazines

### Movies, Music & Games

- Movies & TV
- Blu-ray
- Amazon Instant Video

Comment: There are many tutorials for this on the web

Comment: So you have class. Then, put design on them

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for you to achieve a menu effect. You are gonna need some javascript skills for a simple menu system. **You can also use one of the many available on the internet.**

To apply some style to your code, as it is, you can add the following to your main stylesheet file:

```
li {
    /* here goes the style for both, the menu and submenu. */
}

li.list {
    /* here goes the style for the menu only. */
}
```

Comment: i want menu like which is on flipkart like websites...my code is fetching data from databse so i am getting problem to apply css in that can you please give me the css file correspond to this code

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial 1: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Tutorial 2: http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/

Try this. Not only this there are lots of css tutorials for your question

Thank you